# Set major Xtick with datetime column type

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, datetime-format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1ZSh.png)

I want to clean some matplotlib image, removing the year from every x beside the January ticks.
My date column is in datetime format from pandas

this is my code:

```
df_ref1 = data.groupby(['ref_date'])['fuel'].value_counts().unstack()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4), dpi=200);
df_ref1.plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', stacked=True)
ax.set_title('Distribuição de tipo de combustível')
ax.spines[['top','right', 'left']].set_visible(False)
ax.set_xlabel('')
plt.xticks(rotation = 45,ha='right');
ax.legend(['Gasolina','Disel', 'Álcool'],bbox_to_anchor=(.85, .95, 0, 0), shadow=False, frameon=False)
plt.tight_layout()
```

I tried use:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter('%Y/%m')
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter('%m')
```

Tried using:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y/%m'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(DateFormatter('%m'))
```

but the xticks turn to 1970/01

Without success. Any tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to first truncate the labels to show just year and month and then show only every nth (12th in your case) label, so that you see the first month of each year. Hope the dates are in datetime format.

The data I used...

```
         Date  Petrol  Diesel  Alcohol
0  2021-01-01    1975     320       30
1  2021-02-01    1976     321       31
2  2021-03-01    1977     322       32
3  2021-04-01    1978     323       33
....
22 2022-11-01    1997     342       52
23 2022-12-01    1998     343       53
24 2023-01-01    1999     344       54
```

The updated code...

```
df_ref1=df_ref1.set_index('Date', drop=True) ## Set it so dates are in index
##Your code
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4), dpi=200);
ax.set_title('Distribuição de tipo de combustível')
#ax.spines[['top','right', 'left']].set_visible(False)
ax.set_xlabel('')
df_ref1.plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.xticks(rotation = 45,ha='right')
ax.legend(['Gasolina','Disel', 'Álcool'],bbox_to_anchor=(.85, .95, 0, 0), shadow=False, frameon=False)

## Get the labels using get_text() and set it to show first 7 characters
labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]
labels = [x[:7] for x in labels]
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)        

## Show only the 1st, 13th, ... label
every_nth = 12
for n, label in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()):
    if n % every_nth != 0:
        label.set_visible(False)
```

Output plot

[image]

**Update:**

To show the ticklabels as per comment (Year-Month for Jan and just month for others), use something similar - get the ticklabels, cut the string to first 7 for Jan and 5th to 7th for the other months (two chars only) and display the same... Updated code and plot

```
df_ref1=df_ref1.set_index('Date', drop=True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4), dpi=200);
ax.set_title('Distribuição de tipo de combustível')
ax.set_xlabel('')
df_ref1.plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.xticks(rotation = 45, ha='right')
ax.legend(['Gasolina','Disel', 'Álcool'],bbox_to_anchor=(.85, .95, 0, 0), shadow=False, frameon=False)

## Get the labels using get_text()
labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]

## Show the correct chars based on Jan or not not-Jan
every_nth = 12
for n in range(len(labels)):
    if n % every_nth == 0:
        labels[n]=labels[n][:7] ## Is Jan - show 7 chars
    else:
        labels[n]=labels[n][5:7] ## Is NOT Jan - show 5th to 7th chars

## Update labels
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried change the if statement to show only the 2 last numbers of label, but can't do it.

Comment: Not sure I follow. What are you trying to achieve? You want to see every November instead of Jan?

Comment: I want to show the 2 last number (ie month number) in the others months beside January. 2021-01, 02, 03, 04... until the next year January that will be 2022-01 again

Comment: Check the answer section under update, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah, exactly that!